# python: need help to implement strptime() the right way

Tags: python, datetime, date, time

I am trying to find the difference in days between the current date and the date that I extract from the database (postgresql)

This is my code:

```
    cur.execute('select id, city_id, event_id, duration, DATE(startdate) from main_cityevent where DATE(startdate) <= DATE(NOW())')
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for city_event in rows:
            startdate = str(city_event[4])
            sd = datetime.strptime(startdate, "%Y-%m-%d")
            diff = datetime.datetime.now() - sd
```

the last command (diff = datetime.datetime.now() - sd) gives me an AttributeError.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you do `from datetime import datetime` or `import datetime`?

Comment: yes from datetime import datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably importing `datetime.datetime` (the class) instead of `datetime` (the module).

By always importing the `datetime` module, you can use both `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.date`, which is more appropriate in your case, and has a nice `.today()` method.

And you don't need the whole str() -> strptime() trip, since it should already be a python date object.

Also, you can subtract the dates within the query and get the difference in days:

```
postgres=# select '2011-07-05'::date - current_date;
 ?column? 
----------
       59
(1 row)
```

So your query would be something like

```
SELECT id, city_id, event_id, duration, DATE(startdate)-CURRENT_DATETIME AS days FROM main_cityevent WHERE DATE(startdate) <= DATE(NOW())
```

For a full description of postgres date/time functions, see [here](http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/functions-datetime.html)

On a related note, why do you need to cast 'startdate' inside the query? Are storing it as a string, or a timestamp, or something different? If it's a date, it should be treated as such. Types are important in RDBMS, for correctness and performance. You can (at the very least) have off-by-one errors by subtracting dates and datetimes.

Comment: thanks will check your words out and come back. 'startdate' is a timestamp field. That is why I convert it to date.

Comment: CURRENT_DATETIME was giving me an error so I tried this and it worked: SELECT id, city_id, event_id, duration, DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-DATE(startdate) AS days FROM main_cityevent WHERE DATE(startdate) <= DATE(NOW())

Answer (score 1):

As DiggyF alluded, you should use

```
diff = datetime.now() - sd
```

In the code above, the `datetime.timedelta` object named `diff` will have microseconds resolution.  Unless you intended on microsecond resolution, handling the resultant `timedelta` may be harder than doing this

```
from datetime import date
tmp = startdate.split('-')
sd = date(int(tmp[0]), int(tmp[1]), int(tmp[2]))
diff = date.today() - sd
```

That yields a `datetime.timedelta` with day resolution...